# all values to one key in localStorage was missing

Tags: javascript, session, local-storage, storage, webapi

I stored two keys with some values as JSONObject like

```
 var A = [];
 var B = [];

 var objForA = {};
 objForA.a  = a;
 objForA.b  = b;
 objForA.c  = c;
 .... 

 A.push(objForA);

 var objForB = {};
 objForB.a  = a;
 objForB.b  = b;
 objForB.c  = c;
 .... 
 A.push(objForB);

   localStorage.setItem('A',JSON.stringify(A));

   localStorage.setItem('B',JSON.stringify(B));
```

There is no problem when I get the data in a day, However I have problem when I delete Cache,History,Cookie, etc... when I get the property of localStorage, I only have values to one key, which name of key is B.
The thing that I'm wondering is why only one key's values was missing..

I thought so many times and tried to find the difference between the way I stored A and B... but .. there's nothing different.

when I did console.log , It was looking like

```
A: []
```

I don't know why this values was missing ...... the number of data in A twice of 
data in B. Is it not okay to store a lot of data using localStorage?

How can I figure out the reason ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: it is hard to make a all of code because my company has own but I added more specific. Thank you.

Comment: This does not demonstrate the error. A mre is an example that someone else can run, and observe the same error. You mentioned "delete Cache,History,Cookie, etc" This is probably quite important. What else are you deleting (ect). Have you tried to delete these one at a time to narrow down the cause?

Comment: I understand and thank you for specific advise. I clear Chrome's cookie,cache and history. I try one more time after empty cache and hard reload, values of B which was existing. maybe this is probelm of reload. Thank you.